# KeyError: 'pop from an empty set' when connecting to a Mongodb replica set (motor, pymongo, Tornado)

Tags: python, mongodb, replication, tornado, tornado-motor

I'm connecting to a 3-node replica set running mongoDB in the following manner :

```
DB = motor.MotorReplicaSetConnection("mongodb://user:pass@ip_address:27017", replicaSet='repl_set_name').open_sync().collection_name
```

My replica set works nicely when PRIMARY goes down, another one takes over. But when I do this, my Tornado server throws a `KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'` error upon re-connection.  It appears that Tornado/Motor is not able to reconnect to the new PRIMARY node, I'm not sure why. Even if I add/replace host:port to the connection string, I still get no results. Would this have to do with `read_preference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L-R and I have been debugging this privately, I think the strange error message is a consequence of this Tornado bug:

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/651

... which I've worked around with this commit to Motor:

https://github.com/ajdavis/mongo-python-driver/commit/c7c1614bbf27c3a02ac8c582a8815dee59c39280

Based on your tests it sounds like MotorReplicaSetConnection **can** in fact reconnect to the new primary shortly after it becomes primary, please email me again if that's not the case.